# Lord Ganesha and Lord Kartikeya age difference

Tags: ganesha, kartikeya

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya

How many years age difference was between
Lord Ganesha and Lord Kartikeya?

Thanks & Regards,

Prashant S Akerkar